# Gesture Recognizer not working on iPad but working on iPhone, Why?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, ipad, uigesturerecognizer

Why does this method not work on iPad?

```
- (BOOL)gestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer
shouldReceiveTouch:(UITouch *)touch {

NSLog(@"should receive");
 return YES;
}
```

I have copied the same VC from iPhone Storyboard to iPad storyboard.

The code is simple, and all I'm trying to do is get the NSlog to appear.

While this is working on the iPhone simulator, it is not working on the iPad simulator (or a real device, checked with iPad 4).

Any suggestions as to what I should do to make it work on the iPad?

I am trying to work out what I have missed but nothing comes to mind.

Comment: You're sure you just copied the files? My first instinct is that the UIGestureRecognizerDelegate is not set or improperly set.

Answer (score 0):

**STORYBOARD**

IF you added your gesture recognizer in the storyboard.
Check that you set it as a delegate ..by right clicking the recognizer and dragging the mouse into the view controller. Pop up will show it  clearly.

[image]

**IN CODE**

If the recognizer is added in code..then simply make sure you conform to protocol 
and set its delegate.

```
@interface ViewController : UIViewController <XXXGestureRecognizerDelegate>

-(void)viewDidLoad
{
    self.someGestureRecognizer.delegate = self;

    //other code
}
```

Comment: Hey Earl, thank you for the quick answer, I did it by code, and already delegate it (since the ViewController file use for both iPhone and iPad). any other options you might think of ?

Comment: Did you set your view controller instance that is present in the ipad storyboard to be of your custom class type in class inspector?

Comment: Yes, I have a Web View and it's load perfect with both iPhone and iPad. webView has outlet on storyboard and connected by code (if it matters somehow). the method shouldRecieveTouch is not being called on iPad and it's drive me nuts.

Comment: This is not what I was asking. Can you put a breakpoint on viewDidLoad and launch the app on iPad simulator? If your VC in IB is casted properly, you should see the debugger stop on the breakpoint. If it did not stop there,  you have a problem and then re-read my previous comment and do what it says.

Comment: Hey Earl, I understand what are you saying. I did put a breakpoint on ViewDidLoad and it stop, which means the VC is casted properly. sorry for the misunderstanding before that, what I tried to say is that the webView is code customised and it's appear the same on iPhone and iPad which means that the VC is connected to the right file. what else could be the problem? thank you for your help.

Comment: Our option are getting thinner as we speak :)...check that the root view of the view controller in the iPad Storyboard has userInteractionEnabled to YES in Attributes Inspector. Also check other subviews for that.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/71967/discussion-between-earl-grey-and-xcodenoob).

Comment: Please consider adding the outcome of the chat discussion as an answer to this question.